# Using beautiful soup but not able to access certain information

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently writing a data scraping program to get hockey stats. The page I am getting the information from has some stats that are only available if you click on a javascript button, but when I prettify the soup I can see that all the data is in the *soup* variable. This is an example of the stuff I am trying to access (this is copy pasted from a print(soup))

```
<tr class="ALL5v5 hidden" ><th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="bozakty01" data-stat="player" csk="Bozak,Tyler" ><a href="/players/b/bozakty01.html">Tyler Bozak</a></th><td class="right " data-stat="Cevents" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="on_Cevents" >4</td><td class="right " data-stat="on_opp_Cevents" >5</td><td class="right " data-stat="corsi_for" >44.4</td><td class="right " data-stat="corsi_rel" >-2.5</td><td class="right " data-stat="zs_off" >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="zs_def" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="ozs_pct" >100.0</td><td class="right " data-stat="hits" >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="blocks" >0</td></tr>
<tr class="CL5v5 hidden" ><th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="bozakty01" data-stat="player" csk="Bozak,Tyler" ><a href="/players/b/bozakty01.html">Tyler Bozak</a></th><td class="right " data-stat="Cevents" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="on_Cevents" >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="on_opp_Cevents" >4</td><td class="right " data-stat="corsi_for" >33.3</td><td class="right " data-stat="corsi_rel" >-10.7</td><td class="right " data-stat="zs_off" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="zs_def" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="ozs_pct" ></td><td class="right " data-stat="hits" >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="blocks" >0</td></tr>
```

To access the data I have tried

```
soup.find_all('tr',{'data-stat': "on_Cevents"})
soup.find_all("tr", class_="ALL5v5 hidden")
soup.find_all({'data-stat': "Cevents"})
soup.find_all('td',{'data-stat': "Cevents"})
```

None of these access the information, even though it is all contained in the *soup* variable.

I don't see what the problem is. I'm using the following command

```
players = soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': "player"})
```

to access the player information and that works fine. But I am unable to access the information listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in another section. Please check your configuration again.
Or it results from the other part of html structure which you haven't shown us.

Here is the script I made.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<tr class="ALL5v5 hidden" ><th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="bozakty01" data-stat="player" csk="Bozak,Tyler" ><a href="/players/b/bozakty01.html">Tyler Bozak</a></th><td class="right " data-stat="Cevents" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="on_Cevents" >4</td><td class="right " data-stat="on_opp_Cevents" >5</td><td class="right " data-stat="corsi_for" >44.4</td><td class="right " data-stat="corsi_rel" >-2.5</td><td class="right " data-stat="zs_off" >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="zs_def" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="ozs_pct" >100.0</td><td class="right " data-stat="hits" >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="blocks" >0</td></tr><tr class="CL5v5 hidden" ><th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="bozakty01" data-stat="player" csk="Bozak,Tyler" ><a href="/players/b/bozakty01.html">Tyler Bozak</a></th><td class="right " data-stat="Cevents" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="on_Cevents" >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="on_opp_Cevents" >4</td><td class="right " data-stat="corsi_for" >33.3</td><td class="right " data-stat="corsi_rel" >-10.7</td><td class="right " data-stat="zs_off" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="zs_def" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="ozs_pct" ></td><td class="right " data-stat="hits" >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="blocks" >0</td></tr>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# print(soup)

print(soup.find_all('th', {'data-stat': "player"})) # I think 'th' is correct, not 'td'
print(soup.find_all('tr',{'data-stat': "on_Cevents"}))
print(soup.find_all("tr", class_="ALL5v5 hidden"))
print(soup.find_all({'data-stat': "Cevents"}))
print(soup.find_all('td',{'data-stat': "Cevents"}))
```

And here is the result. I can access the data with some of code which you have tried.

```
[<th class="left " csk="Bozak,Tyler" data-append-csv="bozakty01" data-stat="player" scope="row"><a href="/players/b/bozakty01.html">Tyler Bozak</a></th>, <th class="left " csk="Bozak,Tyler" data-append-csv="bozakty01" data-stat="player" scope="row"><a href="/players/b/bozakty01.html">Tyler Bozak</a></th>]
[]
[<tr class="ALL5v5 hidden"><th class="left " csk="Bozak,Tyler" data-append-csv="bozakty01" data-stat="player" scope="row"><a href="/players/b/bozakty01.html">Tyler Bozak</a></th><td class="right " data-stat="Cevents">0</td><td class="right " data-stat="on_Cevents">4</td><td class="right " data-stat="on_opp_Cevents">5</td><td class="right " data-stat="corsi_for">44.4</td><td class="right " data-stat="corsi_rel">-2.5</td><td class="right " data-stat="zs_off">2</td><td class="right " data-stat="zs_def">0</td><td class="right " data-stat="ozs_pct">100.0</td><td class="right " data-stat="hits">2</td><td class="right " data-stat="blocks">0</td></tr>]
[]
[<td class="right " data-stat="Cevents">0</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="Cevents">0</td>]
```